# Open a new form and bring it to the front whilst the main form is running in the backround

Tags: c#, winforms

My code takes screenshots of the screen and when it recognised certain words a new form should open but it only opens and is brought to the front when the main form is at the front. I want to be able to minimize the form and when it detects a word I want it to bring the new form to the front of the screen, alternatively be able to bring all the forms to the front.
My current code is as follows

```
 public void OpenAutoNotes(string Word,string Text, string Note,string Name)
    {
        if (Find(Word, Text))
        {
            AutoNotes AddNote = new AutoNotes(Note, Name);
            AddNote.Show();
            AddNote.BringToFront();
            
        }
    }
```

The Find() function works perfectly and it opens the form but the form stays minimized or behind the current window

To way I'm calling the form to be opened is using a timer and each tick of the timer the OpenAutoNotes() function is run checking if the word is found.
Here is the rest of the relevant code

```
public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 3000;
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SwitchScan == true)
        {
            SearchKeyWords();
        }
    }
    public void SearchKeyWords()
    {
        Bitmap CurrentImage = SelectImageCapture(499, 499, 540, 200, 0, 0);
        pictureBox1.Image = CurrentImage;
        string MessageText = ImageToText(CurrentImage);
        
        OpenAutoNotes("car", MessageText, "Needs car rented", "TestforText");
        OpenAutoNotes("Car", MessageText, "Needs car rented", "TestforText");
        OpenAutoNotes("cot", MessageText, "Needs a cot", "TestforText");
        OpenAutoNotes("Cot", MessageText, "Needs a cot", "TestforText");
       
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to mentions *something* in relation to the context where this Form is run. How much *int the background* the other Form you're referring to? What other code calls the code you're showing? Are you using some form of Threading to take your screenshots (even a threaded Timer)? Can you show that code?

Comment: @Jimi sorry for the delay I had to leave for work, Yeah there is a lot of other code but this specifically doesn't work as intended. It runs on a timer and so every 5 seconds it takes a screen shot of the screen and then converts all the text into a string, that is then checked to see if it contains a word. When minimized the timer and the code works as intended however it the new form that is shown does not come to the front of the screen. I want it to come up over your internet browser or any other app even if the main form is minimized

Comment: @Jimi I've tried to include all the relevant code now hope this can help :)

Comment: Have you checked `AddNote.InvokeRequired` in `OpenAutoNotes`?  There are a few different timers in .NET.  It should be false.  If not you're not on the GUI thread.  One solution could be to set [`TopMost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=net-5.0) to true.

Comment: @Zer0 I tried the top most and that seemed to work, I wasn't aware of all these functions thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Real Simple change, hope this can help someone else since I couldn't find anything on here with a similar problem

```
if (Find(Word, Text))
        {
            AutoNotes AddNote = new AutoNotes(Note, Name);
            AddNote.TopMost = true;
            AddNote.Show();
            
            
            
        }
```

Comment: Go ahead and mark this as the answer so it's closed out.  Glad my suggestion helped.